# Java timer wont run

Tags: java

So i want to print out a word every second for 10 seconds, but nothing is working
Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.Timer;   

public class Main{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        class TimerListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.out.println("helo");
            }
        }
        ActionListener dummy = new TimerListener();

        Timer power_up_time = new Timer(10000,dummy);
        power_up_time.addActionListener(dummy);
        power_up_time.start();

    }

}
```

EDIT: so i added the start function and it still doesnt work

Comment: Btw, you are adding the listener twice, once in the constructor and once explicitly. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: @Thomas Your first comment is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you need to `start` a `Timer` in order to make it work.

Something like this:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    timer.start();
```

Comment: No, this is the `javax.swing` timer.

Comment: @AndreasFester I see

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Java (from the last ten years or so) I would suggest using a ScehduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("hello"), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
ses.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted is complete you are starting the timer right before the application (i.e. the main thread) terminates. Thus the scheduler won't run long enough to execute the timer.

Try sleeping or running in a loop with some exit condition (that's probably what you'll want to do anyways).

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize and start the Swing toolkit, hence your application immediately terminates.

If you really want to use the Swing `Timer`, you need to show at least some window or dialog, so that the Swing event thread is running, e.g. by adding the following to the end of your `main()` method:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new JFrame("Frame title").setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

See the other answers for alternatives outside of Swing.